# Why does `rm -f !(/var/www/wp)` leave files behind in /var/www?

Tags: bash, shell, rm

Why does the `rm -f !(/var/www/wp)` command have no effect? I want to remove all the files in `/var/www`, except for the `/var/www/wp` directory, which should remain.

```
root@born:~# ls  /var/www
authorize.php  index.html          INSTALL.txt      README.txt  UPGRADE.txt
CHANGELOG.txt  index.php           LICENSE.txt      robots.txt  web.config
COPYRIGHT.txt  INSTALL.mysql.txt   MAINTAINERS.txt  scripts wp
cron.php       INSTALL.pgsql.txt   misc             sites       xmlrpc.php
drupal         install.php         modules          themes
includes       INSTALL.sqlite.txt  profiles         update.php
root@born:~# rm  -f  !(/var/www/wp)
root@born:~# ls  /var/www
authorize.php  index.html          INSTALL.txt      README.txt  UPGRADE.txt
CHANGELOG.txt  index.php           LICENSE.txt      robots.txt  web.config
COPYRIGHT.txt  INSTALL.mysql.txt   MAINTAINERS.txt  scripts wp
cron.php       INSTALL.pgsql.txt   misc             sites       xmlrpc.php
drupal         install.php         modules          themes
includes       INSTALL.sqlite.txt  profiles         update.php
```

Comment: Are you sure that `!(/var/www/wp)` is a shell construct that actually exists? Do you have a pointer to where that's documented? I have never heard of it, and it I try it on bash over here `!(/var/www/wp)` just gets interpreted as `!(/var/www/wp)` (literally) so your command would try to delete a file called `!(/var/www/wp)`.

Comment: /var/www/wp  is a directory not a file not a link .i want to keep the directory ,all other files and directories removed.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but that isn't what I asked.

Comment: @Celada `!(/var/www/wp)` is a bash `extglob` which is a feature that can be turned on or off with `shopt`.

Comment: A directory won't be deleted by `rm` anyway! `rm` only works on files, it will just warn you that you gave directories as arguments. So... always ask the right questions. Secondly, why don't you `cd` there before removing stuff? What you are doing is extermely dangerous and you may have damaged your home directory. Read the answer by Michael.

Comment: Next time ask a single question per post, instead of two.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can read [Michael Homer's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/191356/38906) to know the reason.

To remove all things in `/var/www` exclude `wp`, POSIXly:

```
find /var/www -path /var/www/wp -prune -o ! -path /var/www -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Answer (score 37):

**If you're running bash ≥4.3, then if you have backups, now would be a good time to find them**.

I assume you're using Bash. The [`!(...)` filename expansion pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) expands to every existing path that doesn't match the pattern *at the point it's used*. That is:

```
echo rm  -f  !(/var/www/wp)
```

expands to every filename in the current directory that isn't "/var/www/wp". That is every file in the current directory. In essence, you ran `rm -f *` in `~`. **Do not run the `rm` command above**.

To get the effect you wanted, use the pattern only for the part of the path you want it (not) to match, just like you would for `*`, `{a,b,c}`, or any other pattern. The command:

```
echo rm -f /var/www/!(wp)
```

will print out the command you wanted to run.

I don't, to be honest, suggest doing things this way - it's prone to exactly the sort of issue you had here, and others. Something with `find` is easier to follow. At the very least, `echo` the command before you run it and you'll see what is happening.

Comment: This won't remove hidden files and directories.

Comment: Good answer. I'd also add this: at least `cd` to the directory before removing anything. Removing things from far away is always dangerous (especially if there are relative paths or globs involved).

Comment: On what version of bash did you see this? On ksh 93u+ and on bash 4.2 with `shopt -s extglob`, `echo !(/var/www/wp)` leaves the pattern unchanged, as does as far as I can tell any pattern where a slash is within `!(…)`

Comment: @Gilles: `GNU bash, version 4.3.33(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)`

Comment: But you're right, 3.2 doesn't do it. It does seem like a misfeature to have added that behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. That's a weird incompatible change — departing from ksh, zsh, and previous versions of bash, to do something which I can't fathom being useful. [The behavior of `!(…)` changed in bash 4.3](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2014-06/msg00063.html), but I don't get the impression that matching all files in the current directory with a pattern like `!(/)` was intended.

Answer (score 0):

Find, grep and xargs combination

```
find /var/www/ -maxdepth 1|grep -v wp|xargs rm -rf
```

And can be convert into bash file, for more generalized purpose.

```
#!bash
# $1 -- directory 
# $2 -- Exception filename or directory name
find "$1" -maxdepth 1|grep -v "$2"|xargs rm -rf
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 user@host:~$ rm --help
Usage: rm [OPTION]... FILE...
Remove (unlink) the FILE(s).

  -f, --force           ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
  -i                    prompt before every removal
  -I                    prompt once before removing more than three files, or
                          when removing recursively.  Less intrusive than -i,
                          while still giving protection against most mistakes
      --interactive[=WHEN]  prompt according to WHEN: never, once (-I), or
                          always (-i).  Without WHEN, prompt always
      --one-file-system  when removing a hierarchy recursively, skip any
                          directory that is on a file system different from
                          that of the corresponding command line argument
      --no-preserve-root  do not treat '/' specially
      --preserve-root   do not remove '/' (default)
  -r, -R, --recursive   remove directories and their contents recursively
  -d, --dir             remove empty directories
  -v, --verbose         explain what is being done
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

By default, rm does not remove directories.  Use the --recursive (-r or -R)
option to remove each listed directory, too, along with all of its contents.

To remove a file whose name starts with a '-', for example '-foo',
use one of these commands:
  rm -- -foo

  rm ./-foo

Note that if you use rm to remove a file, it might be possible to recover
some of its contents, given sufficient expertise and/or time.  For greater
assurance that the contents are truly unrecoverable, consider using shred.

Report rm bugs to bug-coreutils@gnu.org
GNU coreutils home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>
For complete documentation, run: info coreutils 'rm invocation'
```

> **Idea for a workaround:**
>
> :~$
>
> ```
> cd /var/www
>     mkdir /opt/move
>     mv wp /opt/move/wp
>     rm -r *
>     mv /opt/wp /var/www/wp
> [optional ;)] chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
> ```

**user@host:~$ mv Reference:**

```
mv --help
Usage: mv [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
  or:  mv [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
  or:  mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
Rename SOURCE to DEST, or move SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
      --backup[=CONTROL]       make a backup of each existing destination file
  -b                           like --backup but does not accept an argument
  -f, --force                  do not prompt before overwriting
  -i, --interactive            prompt before overwrite
  -n, --no-clobber             do not overwrite an existing file
If you specify more than one of -i, -f, -n, only the final one takes effect.
      --strip-trailing-slashes  remove any trailing slashes from each SOURCE
                                 argument
  -S, --suffix=SUFFIX          override the usual backup suffix
  -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY  move all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
  -T, --no-target-directory    treat DEST as a normal file
  -u, --update                 move only when the SOURCE file is newer
                                 than the destination file or when the
                                 destination file is missing
  -v, --verbose                explain what is being done
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

The backup suffix is '~', unless set with --suffix or SIMPLE_BACKUP_SUFFIX.
The version control method may be selected via the --backup option or through
the VERSION_CONTROL environment variable.  Here are the values:

  none, off       never make backups (even if --backup is given)
  numbered, t     make numbered backups
  existing, nil   numbered if numbered backups exist, simple otherwise
  simple, never   always make simple backups

Report mv bugs to bug-coreutils@gnu.org
GNU coreutils home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>
For complete documentation, run: info coreutils 'mv invocation'
```

**user@host:~$ chown Reference:**

```
chown --help                                                                                                                              
    Usage: chown [OPTION]... [OWNER][:[GROUP]] FILE...                                                                                                           
      or:  chown [OPTION]... --reference=RFILE FILE...                                                                                                           
    Change the owner and/or group of each FILE to OWNER and/or GROUP.                                                                                            
    With --reference, change the owner and group of each FILE to those of RFILE.                                                                                 

      -c, --changes          like verbose but report only when a change is made                                                                                  
      -f, --silent, --quiet  suppress most error messages                                                                                                        
      -v, --verbose          output a diagnostic for every file processed                                                                                        
          --dereference      affect the referent of each symbolic link (this is                                                                                  
                             the default), rather than the symbolic link itself                                                                                  
      -h, --no-dereference   affect symbolic links instead of any referenced file                                                                                
                             (useful only on systems that can change the                                                                                         
                             ownership of a symlink)                                                                                                             
          --from=CURRENT_OWNER:CURRENT_GROUP                                                                                                                     
                             change the owner and/or group of each file only if                                                                                  
                             its current owner and/or group match those specified                                                                                
                             here.  Either may be omitted, in which case a match                                                                                 
                             is not required for the omitted attribute                                                                                           
          --no-preserve-root  do not treat '/' specially (the default)                                                                                           
          --preserve-root    fail to operate recursively on '/'                                                                                                  
          --reference=RFILE  use RFILE's owner and group rather than                                                                                             
                             specifying OWNER:GROUP values
      -R, --recursive        operate on files and directories recursively

    The following options modify how a hierarchy is traversed when the -R
    option is also specified.  If more than one is specified, only the final
    one takes effect.

      -H                     if a command line argument is a symbolic link
                             to a directory, traverse it
      -L                     traverse every symbolic link to a directory
                             encountered
      -P                     do not traverse any symbolic links (default)

          --help     display this help and exit
          --version  output version information and exit

    Owner is unchanged if missing.  Group is unchanged if missing, but changed
    to login group if implied by a ':' following a symbolic OWNER.
    OWNER and GROUP may be numeric as well as symbolic.

    Examples:
      chown root /u        Change the owner of /u to "root".
      chown root:staff /u  Likewise, but also change its group to "staff".
      chown -hR root /u    Change the owner of /u and subfiles to "root".

    Report chown bugs to bug-coreutils@gnu.org
    GNU coreutils home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
    General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>
    For complete documentation, run: info coreutils 'chown invocation'
```