# Remove everything except csv file Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, wildcards, rm

I would like to delete everything from a folder except csv files

I am trying with a bash script and I am getting this error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

This is my script :

```
 PATH=/tmp/

 run_spark_local
 rm -v !($PATH*.csv)

 cp -r $PATH /data/logs/
```

I have also tried

```
rm -v !("$PATH*.csv")
```

Comment: What is `run_spark_local`?

Comment: Turn on  extglob- `shopt -s extglob`.

Comment: Clearing out `/tmp` could have adverse consequences on other programs running on the system.

Comment: @Jesse_b a function to run my spark app

Comment: This is why you don't use ALLCAPS variable names in your code.

Comment: Note that using `!(...)` with a path like that [can be dangerous](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/191356/73093) and would probably be good to avoid anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should avoid setting the `PATH` variable.  This is used by your shell to find valid commands, setting it to `/tmp/` is going to prevent the script from being able to find the `rm` and `cp` commands altogether.

You can accomplish what you want with the following `find` command:

```
find /tmp -not -name '*.csv' -not -path /tmp -exec rm -vr {} \;
```

Note: this will delete any subdirectories under /tmp as well.  If you do not want this you must change to:

```
find /tmp -not -name '*.csv' -type f -exec rm -v {} \;
```

Another note: This will still recurse into the subdirectories and delete the files in them.  If you do not want this you can use the `maxdepth` argument:

```
find /tmp -not -name '*.csv' -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm -v {} \;
```

---

Extra note:  I would never run a `find ... -exec` command that you find online without verifying it will do what you need it to do first.  You should run:

```
find /tmp -not -name '*.csv' -not -path /tmp
```

And verify it is finding only the files you want before adding the `-exec rm -vr {} \;` bit.

Comment: find /tmp -not -name '*.csv' -not -path /tmp -exec rm -vr {} \;

This Worked well for me Thank you 

What if i want to do the same thing but in the hdfs .  does this work ?
  hdfs dfs find /tmp -not -name '*.csv' -not -path /tmp -exec rm -vr {} \;

Answer (score 6):

Please do not set $PATH it is a environment variable.

For BASH, so long as the [extglob](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) shell option is enabled (that is the default for a lot of linux distributions), it is just:

```
rm !(*.csv)
```

With a folder path it will be something like...

```
rm yourfolder/!(*.csv)
```

If you think extglob is not enabled in your environment, just do this:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of deleting everything else in `/tmp`, I’d recommend only copying the files you’re interested in:

```
cp /tmp/*.csv /data/logs/
```

or even

```
mv /tmp/*.csv /data/logs/
```

if you don’t need to keep them in `/tmp`.

This assumes that all the files you’re interested in are directly in `/tmp`; your use of `rm` suggests that they are.

Since `/tmp` is a shared temporary directory, it could contain other files which other running processes expect to find there, and deleting everything in `/tmp` apart from the CSV files could have adverse consequences. As others have mentioned, you shouldn’t change `PATH` either since your shell uses that to find the commands you’re using.

Comment: or just moving for somewhere....